# Recuperar valor de dos niveles superiores para un registro concreto

Tags: python-3.x, django, listview, djangorestframework

Como recupero el valor de Entities.name para un registro de ProjectsComments.

Top model

```
class Entities(models.Model): 
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Código', max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Codigo de entidad.')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre', unique=True,
                                   help_text='Nombre de la entidad.')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item
```

Second Level:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entities, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="Entidad")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.entity}' + ' \ ' + f'{self.code}' + ' \ ' + f'{self.name}'  # + ' \ ' + f'{self.phase}'

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['entity'] = self.entity.toJSON()
        return item
```

Third Level

```
class ProjectsComments(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=0, verbose_name='Proyecto',
                                   help_text='Proyecto')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date}' + f' ' + f'#' + f'{self.user}' + f'# ' + f'{self.comment}'

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['project'] = self.project.toJSON()
        item['entity'] = Entities.objects.get(pk = )
        item['user'] = self.user.toJSON()
        return item
```

Necesitaría que de projectcommentsListView obtenga el valor de ProjectsComments__Projects__Entity.name

He intentado entrar en ProjectsComments.toJSON() con:

item['entity'] = Entities.objets.get(pk = )

Y

item['entity'] = self.entity.toJSON()
Ya no lo sé.

Comment: ¿No sería `objeto_project_commens.toJSON()["project"]["entity"]["name"]`? Por otro lado, sobra la línea `item['entity']=Entitites.ojects.get(pk=)`, entre otras cosas porque está incompleta (¿qué valor asignas a `pk`?) pero además porque no es necesaria ya que el "subcampo" entity ya se crea en el `toJSON()` del objeto `Projects`.

Comment: Si, efectivamente esa línea está incompleta. Era a modo de ejemplo que tambien lo intenté de esa manera.

Finalmente, hablando con un compañero de rebote, me lo ha resuelto con lo siguiente:

item['entity'] = self.project.entity.toJSON()

Simple y Sencillo.

Comment: Ah, no era eso lo que había entendido de tu pregunta. Creía que querías recuperar el nombre de la entidad a partir del json que te retornaba el `.toJSON()` del projectcomments.

Comment: Perdón si me expliqué mal :).

Llevo poco tiempo con django (y he conseguido metérselo a mi dpto a la fuerza jejeje y estoy solo en la pelea que sin formación ni nada y con muchas cosas no se como explicarme para lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO :

La necesidad quedaría resuelto con un árbol de niveles desde los propios modelos.

Nivel3 FK Nivel2
Nivel2 FK Nivel1

Nivel3:

```
    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['field'] = self.nivel2.nivel1.toJSON() 
        return item
```